# How Windows 10 calculates display size?

Tags: windows

So how Windows 'knows' the size of screen? I'm sure it is not on the sole basis of screen resolution. As well as, any method to alter its perceived size will be appreciated.

Comment: [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data). It's [pretty useful](https://superuser.com/q/1058802/194694).

Answer (score 1):

EDID - Extended Display Identification Data. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data),

> EDID data structure includes manufacturer name and serial number, product type, phosphor or filter type, timings supported by the display, **display size**, luminance data and (for digital displays only) pixel mapping data.

Long story short, your monitor tells your computer, along with a lot of other things. More specifically, the Horizontal and Vertical lengths are given in the 21st and 22nd byte of the EDID. (You can see that from the table on Wikipedia)

You're right, it isn't on the basis of screen resolution since multiple displays can have the same screen resolution but different screen sizes.

> alter it's perceived size

I personally do not know of any method, and honestly can't think of any reason why, since you should just be able to adjust the screen resolution accordingly.