# Checking the luminance range of a monitor

Tags: display, display-settings

I'm wondering if it's possible to check to luminance range of my monitor. I know that there are external device to measure it, but I'd like only to read in some window this characteristic, i. e. nominal values.

---

EDIT: I tried to find the display model by using MonitorInfoView, but without any success.

[image]

Comment: The manufacturer's spec sheet should have this as a nominal value. Nothing *inside* the display or computer can read the *true* value. For that you need a colorimeter.

Comment: Hello @Tetsujin thank you for your comment. Is it possible that the range of the luminance is readable because it can be written in the firmware of the monitor?

Comment: Were you successful in this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no standardized way displays could indicate that to hosts, at least for non-HDR displays.

Your best bet is [reading display model from EDID](https://superuser.com/a/1058803/194694) and looking up its specs online.

I think HDR displays can indicate their maximum brightness capabilities, but that wouldn't be what the display uses unless you're displaying HDR-compatible media.

Comment: Hello @gronostaj thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi @gronostaj can you see the edit of my question please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Your monitor doesn't seem to be reporting complete EDID info. Are you maybe connecting it through an adapter? What about taking a look at the sticker at the back to check the model? Is there at least a manufacturer logo at the front? Can you tell roughly when it could have been purchased? What connectors are available at the back/sides?

Comment: it's the integrated monitor of my laptop ASUS N550JK-CM097H. I tried to find information exploiting the model of my laptop, but informations about the display luminance are not available.

Comment: It will most likely be in the 250-300 nits range, as measured for [this review](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-N550JK-CN109H-Notebook-Review.117726.0.html).

Comment: thank you very much for your very useful research.